# Ways to fly around the battlefield and still get have a Full action left to use on other things?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement

I'm looking for a way for a 10th level Witch to zip around the battlefield, in the air, without needing to use a Move action for it.

One can control a mount (on land or in the air) as a free action, as long as one can beast a DC 5 Ride check...so presumably a flying mount is one option.

Carpet of Flying says

> each carpet has its own command word to activate it—if the device is within voice range, the command word activates it, whether the speaker is on the rug or not. The carpet is then controlled by spoken directions.

...which I suspect means it can be controlled as a free action (or without an action).

I'm wondering:

- Am I correct that one can control a flying mount or a flying carpet, while still taking a full action?
- Are there other options I haven't thought of, that allow zipping around in the air without spending a Move action?

Comment: Yes, and quickened dimension door.

Comment: A 10th-level witch couldn't quicken Dimension Door yet. You don't get spell slots that high until Level 15, and even then you only get one shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a magic carpet or flying mount (assuming you're not pushing them) will work. Also, the inexpensive [Cackling Hag's Blouse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/blouse-cackling-hag-s) lets you cackle 2xday as a swift action.

I play a witch and usually don't need much of those move actions though; you have to be within 30' for your hexes to proc so usually I fly over and then just adjust around... Plus you don't always have to start cackling immediately (like misfortune post level 8, or when someone's clearly gonna die by PC action before the hex will be effective again).

Also, you can Levitate and have some summoned creature push/drag you around...